# How do I properly use the map function to get the index of the element in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, shopify, gatsby

Hello I am trying to find the index of the element in an array using map so that eventually I can create a onClick function that will change the image based on that index.

However when I add index to my map function I then get an error stating that the img is not defined.

```
const currentIndex = 0;

const gallery = 
  product.images.length > 1 ? (
    <Grid gap={2} columns={5}>
      {product.images.map(img, index => (
        <GatsbyImage 
          image={img.gatsbyImageData}
          key={img.id}
          alt={product.title}
        />
      ))}
    </Grid>
  ) : null;
```

The above code displays a list of thumbnail size images. I would like to eventually be able to click on each image and have the larger image appear.

Code for the larger image is below.

```
<div>
  <GatsbyImage
    image={product.images[currentIndex].gatsbyImageData}
    alt={product.title}
  />
  {gallery}
</div>
```

Comment: Did you forget parentheses for the function argument? `.map( (img, index) => {/*...*/} )`

Comment: The parentheses around parameter definitions for arrow functions are optional when, and *only* when there is exactly **one** parameter. You have **two**.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for showing the duplicate question. I looked for ages trying to find a similar question to mine. I don't like posting questions unless I need to. But for some reason none of my searches yielded that question. Not even when I typed out my question. anyway thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple parenthesis fix:

```
const currentIndex = 0;

const gallery = 
  product.images.length > 1 ? (
    <Grid gap={2} columns={5}>
      {product.images.map((img, index) => (
        <GatsbyImage 
          image={img.gatsbyImageData}
          key={img.id}
          alt={product.title}
        />
      ))}
    </Grid>
  ) : null;
```

Make sure to not pass two values, but one value to Array.map: a function with its own optional parameter called 'index'

Consider expanding your work to a function that you can just reference, to make life easier, and code more legible, like this:

```
const currentIndex = 0;

const mapper = (img, index) => (
  <GatsbyImage image={img.gatsbyImageData} key={img.id} alt={product.title} />
);

const gallery =
  product.images.length > 1 ? (
    <Grid gap={2} columns={5}>
      {product.images.map(mapper)}
    </Grid>
  ) : null;
```

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax